# stack new - which template for distributed haskell?

Tags: distributed-computing, haskell-stack

The first step of [the distributed-haskell tutorial](http://haskell-distributed.github.io/tutorials/1ch.html) is to

```
stack new
```

in a fresh directory. But if I try that, I get:

> Missing: PACKAGE_NAME
>   Usage: stack.exe new PACKAGE_NAME [--bare] [TEMPLATE_NAME]
>                        [-p|--param KEY:VALUE] [DIRS] [--solver] [--omit-packages]
>                        [--force] [--ignore-subdirs] [--help]
>     Create a new project from a template. Run `stack templates' to see available
>     templates.

I guess the tutorial is written for another version of the stack tool. Or that the authors of the tutorial have forgotten to mention their default settings they use. Something like that.

So, the question remains - in order to continue following that tutorial - which of the available templates am I supposed to use?

Comment: I don't see any indication that the tutorial uses a special template, it looks like they're going with the default "new-template" template. As the usage indicates you do have to specify a package name though, i.e. run `stack new my-pkg` to create a project containing a single package called `my-pkg`.

Comment: @sjakobi I might be wrong - but from the text on that page, I think they try to achieve the equivalent of what would be an "Empty solution" in Visual Studio. So calling it without a package name kind of seems reasonable. Also compare to rust ``cargo new``. So my bet is still, that there is something wrong with the stack version of mine or similar.

Comment: As far as I can remember `stack new` has always demanded a package name argument. Even if it didn't, the package name doesn't really change the contents of the new project.